# Image animation with mouse y movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i make websites as a hobby nothing professional,
but i found a really well made website and i thought it had some things i never saw being used before like 3 images in one div ( which i searched up and found out how to do it ).

But what i could not simply google was how he made each image move seperately on mouse y movement, i do not know if this is doable with just css or would i need to use javascript as well? ( note: i hardly know any javascript ).

Here is the website: https://buy.cosmicpvp.com/
what i was referring to is the top portion of the website.

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how/where to post questions. Do a search for _Mouse Parallax_ and you will get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the Parallax effect.

Looks like the website in question used [this jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Interactive-Mouse-Hover-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-Mouse-Parallax.html) for it.
To answer your question, you most certainly need JavaScript.

Comment: Amazing!
That is almost what i needed, i would like to reproduce exactly what the website i provided did, i can manage to play around with the code to get it to the way i whant, except with the javascript. would you mind telling me what i would need to modify the javascript to make it only move in horizontal mouse movements?

Comment: You disable the `yparallax` in the option object: `$('#background').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 5 });` ->`$('#background').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 5, yparallax: false });`

Comment: thanks for the help,
but unfortuneatly that did not work.

$('#background').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 5, yparallax: false });

nothing seemed to change

Comment: This is the code the website you referred to is using: `$('#background-5').mouseParallax({ moveFactor: 1, yparallax: false, imgWidth:1900 });`. I can't really bother looking into the plugin, just take a look at the source of the website and see what's different `view-source:https://buy.cosmicpvp.com/`

Comment: thanks for the help,
with all the information you gave me i am sure i can figure the rest out.

you're awesome!